# Adding Android Environment to IBM MobileFirst Shell component

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am using IBM MFP Studio 7.1 and  following the tutorial on how to add an android environment to a Shell component: [Documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/advanced-topics/shell-development-concepts/android-shell-development/). As soon as I add the environment, I get this error:

[2016-04-05 08:45:58] FWLST1040E: android build failed: Trying to build an inner application but the shell resources do not contain a native template for environment android
[2016-04-05 08:45:59]             Application 'MyShellTest' with environment 'android' build finished with errors.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation's pictures are a bit misleading. I am supposed to add it to the Shell component and not the test application. The first picture in the documentation refers to MyShellTest. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Don't use shell... really, just don't. :)

Comment: @IdanAdar lol....I understand but again I have to know how these work since I'm looking at the certification. I have no choice